# TWIG, dynamic associative array key

Tags: twig

I need to create a array with a dynamic key.

Example:

```
{% set key = 'a' %}
{% set value = 'b' %}
{% set array = {key:value} %}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I find a workaround for this problem: if you surround the `key` with parenthesis the key of array take the value of the variable instead of the name. So try simple this:

```
{% set array = { (key): value} %}
```

[Here](http://twigfiddle.com/srax5p) a working solutions